# How can I remove a suggestion from the Chrome address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I've got a couple of URL autocomplete suggestions where Chrome suggests the wrong URL consistently.

How can I delete the incorrect entry from the address bar's suggestion list? The page I want shows up too but it's never the first result.

Comment: For a answer for linux look at this answer:  https://superuser.com/a/1269394/511365

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When the suggestion loads up, navigate to the URL suggestion you want to delete using <kbd>↑</kbd> or  <kbd>↓</kbd> keys on keyboard and 
press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, it removes the wrong entry.

For Mac, it's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> +<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Had to try it a couple times but it worked!

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes, it takes a couple of times for it to work out(idk why) but glad it worked.

Comment: doesn't work on Windows

Comment: @Jonathan It works now (Using chrome version 35.0.1916.114)

Comment: For the Mac, it's `Shift` + `Fn` + `Delete`.

Answer (score 4):

When the suggestions loads in suggestion box

[image]

Navigate to the URL suggestion you want to delete using <kbd>↑</kbd> or  <kbd>↓</kbd> keys on keyboard and press

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on a PC.
**OR**
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on a Mac.
**OR**
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on a Chromebook.

References -

- [Remove specific
  predictions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en)
- [pcworld article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2098431/how-to-erase-specific-autosuggested-urls-from-chrome-firefox-and-ie.html)

Comment: This doesn't work on a chromebook.