# How to remove specific domain from address bar typing suggestion?

Tags: firefox, address-bar

I start typing `whatev`, and it suggests `whateverdomain.com` (but should `whateverdomain.net`). I visited `whateverdomain.com` once by mistake, and now it got stuck and outweights `whateverdomain.net` somehow, even though I type the latter more often.

How to remove this specific suggesting from Firefox profile?

[Shift](https://superuser.com/questions/382437/how-can-i-remove-a-suggestion-from-the-chrome-address-bar)+[Del](https://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls-from-the-url-bar) obviously fails, as it is not Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start typing it, and when the list "pops down", use the <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow key until the *incorrect* entry is selected, then press <kbd>Del</kbd>.

If the entry appears only as pre-selected text and is absent from the list, change the "When using the location bar, suggest:" setting in "Privacy" tab in "Preferences" to "Bookmarks and history", so the offending entry becomes selectable.

Comment: Does not work. I start typing: `whatev`... Firefox appends `whatev{selection starts}erdomain.com{selection ends}`. I press `Down` - nothing changes (there is no popdown list), I press `Del` - the selected part of the text disappears, not not permanently. It reappears if I start typing it again. The Firefox version in questoin is 17esr.

Comment: @Vi Is it not possible to upgrade to Firefox 30?

Comment: Found the workaround: I temporarily changed "When using the location bar, suggest:" from "Bookmarks" to "Bookmarks and History". That way I'm able to to invoke the entry in the explicit list.

Comment: I usually stick at some ESR version for a long time (updating it within major version). I don't always like "new feelings" from browser updates. By the time I actually update the browser (not to the recent version), the workarounds for new misfeatues are already available.

Comment: @Vi. Exactly what FF version do you have?

Comment: 17.0.6

Comment: @Vi. OK, I am downloading it. I will see if there is actually a way to do it.

Comment: Please include the information about the "Preferences" setting that affect visibility of the suggestion in the list (so it can be `Del`ed)

Comment: @Vi. So what *was* it set to before?

Comment: @Vi. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15096/discussion-between-benjiwiebe-and-vi).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I deleted all history for one domain but still firefox suggested that domain. What turned out was that I had one bookmark with that domain under

```
Menu -> History -> View All History -> All Bookmarks -> Unsorted Bookmarks
```

(don't know how it get there). I've deleted it and that fixed my problem.