# How to delete address bar suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

You know when you type something into the address bar, and it comes up with suggestions and sites you have visited, is there any way to delete those?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history

Answer (score 145):

Highlight the entry and:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on a PC
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> a Mac

#### To disable autocomplete in general

- open the Chrome Settings
- Show advanced settings (at the bottom)
- Under Privacy, uncheck

  - `"Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar."`
  - `use a prediction service to load pages more quickly`

The completions will still appear as dropdown items and you can arrow down to select them - if you want to, but they won't be automatically applied.

- reference - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en

Comment: Or if you have a mac laptop without a delete button: shift + fn + backspace.

Comment: For those with no "function" key on their keyboard attached to a mac, it's "shirt + delete" (oddly).

Comment: Confusingly, highlighting just with the mouse cursor doesn’t work!  Needs to be by keyboard.  I suggested an edit to address this.

Comment: @Matt I came here with a question that you answered: "What about the 70% of mac keyboards that don't have a freakin delete key?". Good job on Apple picking something so obnoxious :/ Thanks for the answer though -- +1!

Comment: Why in hell does the mac version not show up everywhere? Took me way too long to find this solution.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm using Chrome on Windows, and shift-delete *does* temporarily remove the suggestion from the autocomplete list, but if I type the same characters again, the suggestion reappears. The site is neither in my history nor in my bookmarks.

Comment: The mac instructions here are incorrect: the answer is "shift + delete" just like on the PC, it's just that on some keyboards pressing delete may require pressing the Fn key. But if your keyboard has an actual delete key (note I mean the old-school delete key, _not_ backspace) then the answer is just "shift + delete".

Answer (score 22):

Chances are you have the site bookmarked

Enter the site so as it does show up in your browser history. Then go into your history, you'll probably see a star at the end of the url in the history page. Click on that and it'll remove it from bookmarks, then you can delete the site normally.

Comment: You can also directly click on the star in the address bar and then click Remove.

Comment: This is what mine turned out to be.  If Shift-Del doesn't work, check your bookmarks.

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me, didn't realize that google suggests urls from bookmarks too.

Answer (score 6):

On linux (ubuntu) with chrome: while starting typing and then having specific item highlighted as suggestion: <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Tried on chromium 62.0.3202.89 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 17.10 (64-bit), did not work

Comment: I am on chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Tried it again. Definitely works.

Comment: Not working on Google Chrome Version 78.0... (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu Mate 18.04. It may be that this kind of key combination is absorbed from a higher layer and never reach Chrome!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by removing them from Chrome history:

- presss <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or just navigate to `chrome://history`
- look for the items you want to remove (you can even use the search box at the top right) and check the box next to them
- click "Remove selected items"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to hit the delete button when you see the suggestion- that will delete that particular site alone from history. If you want to delete all, clear your browsing history. Best solution would be using the browser in private mode when you don't want that for few sites alone. Permanent solution would be changing the privacy settings in your browser.